# Angular 10 - build failed when using jsPDF

Tags: angular, typescript, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I have an Angular 10.2.0 project. Node.js v14.21.2. I want to use [jsPDF](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jspdf) and [jsPDF-AutoTable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jspdf-autotable) packages in my app.

**tsconfig.json:**

```
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "downlevelIteration": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "importHelpers": true,
        "target": "es2015",
        "module": "es2020",
        "lib": [
        "es2019",
        "es2018",
        "dom"
        ]
    }
}
```

**package.json:**

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "jspdf": "^2.5.1",
    "jspdf-autotable": "^3.5.28",
    ...
}
```

**pdf.component.ts:**

```
import { jsPDF } from "jspdf"; 
//import jsPDF from "jspdf" -> This is not working as well.
import autoTable from 'jspdf-autotable'

getPDF() {
    const doc = new jsPDF();
    
    // Some text and tables adding to pdf.
    
    autoTable(doc, {
        startY: 35,
        theme: 'plain',
        tableLineWidth: 0.1,
        tableLineColor: '#777',
        head: [...],
        body: [...]
    });
    
    // Some text and tables adding to pdf.
    
    doc.output('pdfobjectnewwindow');
}
```

I've installed, declared and used them as instructed, and they are working fine.

But, when I try to build my project for deployment with `ng build --prod`, it gets failed while `Generating ES5 bundles for differential loading...` and gives me this error:

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Call retries were exceeded
See "log" for further details.
```

And the log file says:

```
[error] Error: Call retries were exceeded
    at ChildProcessWorker.initialize (...\node_modules\jest-worker\build\workers\ChildProcessWorker.js:193:21)
    at ChildProcessWorker._onExit (...\node_modules\jest-worker\build\workers\ChildProcessWorker.js:274:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:285:12)
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: which node/angular version are you trying this for?

Comment: @Mohit "@angular/core": "~10.2.0", and node.js v14.21.2